# `svn checkout` over HTTP gives error E000104 but `svn ls` works

Tags: ubuntu, http, subversion

I am unable to `svn checkout` a repository (served over HTTP) from work but I can from home. I *am*, however, able to `svn list` as well as view the repository in a web browser when at work. This is the message I see (repo URL is redacted to prevent spamming the server):

```bsh
$ svn co http://-------.---/svn/project
svn: E000104: Error running context: Connection reset by peer
```

The first time I try to checkout, it will fetch a few directories (just the empty directories, not the contents) before giving the error message. I suspect a firewall issue: this [superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/1255260/svn-e000104-error-running-context-connection-reset-by-peer) and this [Google Groups question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/kaldi-help/WRhOucYpueA/AaC8WoEHCQAJ) show the same symptoms, and a firewall was suggested as the culprit, but neither question has a resolution. These StackOverflow questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7249097/what-ports-need-to-be-open-for-tortoisesvn-to-authenticate-clear-text-and-comm) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26323119/svn-e000104-error-running-context-connection-reset-by-peer)) describe issues with committing but not with checking out.

Complicating the situation, I am able to checkout a different repository (also served via HTTP, but from a different server), but the first server doesn't seem to be broken (recall I can checkout from home). Neither uses HTTPS, but could there be other settings that make a difference?

Changing the port does not work. Perhaps other ports are blocked because the process hangs until the request times out:

```bsh
$ svn co http://-------.---:8080/svn/project
svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://-------.---:8080/svn/project'
svn: E000110: Error running context: Connection timed out
```

I'm running Pop!_OS 18.10 (Ubuntu derivative).

Comment: What is the reason for the downvote? I'm happy to revise the question if it doesn't follow convention somehow.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7249097/what-ports-need-to-be-open-for-tortoisesvn-to-authenticate-clear-text-and-comm

Comment: Looks like an MTU problem. Ask your firewall administrators if they're dropping ICMP "fragmentation needed" packets (and if they are, tell them not to).

Comment: @XTian thanks but that question is about committing. I am having trouble with checkouts. I've revised my question to show my research.

Comment: @roaima Thanks for the suggestion, I've passed it along to IT. But do you think that could be the case given I can checkout from another HTTP repository? Maybe the second server has an MTU size compatible with my local network? (forgive me if I sound ignorant; networking isn't my strength)

Comment: A silly question: DId you try to `svn up` instead of `svn co`? Since "part" of the repo is already there, may be it fixes. Another shot I tryed in the past was to delete the entire working copy and do it again from zero. Because sometimes if the connection is interrupted during the check out, is the most safe way to preserve the integrity

Comment: @Juan thanks for the suggestion. I did try `svn up` to no avail. And I tried deleting the repo and re-checking out multiple times. It wasn't that something was broken in my local checkout, it was a problem with the network (firewall or otherwise). Unfortunately (?) IT whitelisted the site so whatever problem I had before is now gone and I can no longer debug, but at least I can checkout now.